# getJSON is not getting called onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have an input field for pwd and onchange I have used getJSON. But it is not getting called. I have some sysout in the controller once the authenticationChk.html is getting called but not seeing it in console.

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/finTransCommon.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
//...

    $("#pwdOverride").change(function(){
        var pwdOverride = $("#pwdOverride").val();          
        $.getJSON(
            '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/transaction/authenticationChk.html',
            {paramFilter:'PROFILE',pwdOverride:pwdOverride},
            function(data){
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        )
        .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
        .error(function() { alert("error"); })
        .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });                   
    });

..//
```

Controller code:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticationChk.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String authenticationChk(@RequestParam("crid") String pwdOverride) throws Exception {
    try{
    userAuthenticationService.authenticateUser("Y8RRP0", pwdOverride);
    }catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        System.out.println("new Gson().toJson(false) .. exception "+new Gson().toJson(false));
        return (new Gson().toJson(false));
    }
    System.out.println("new Gson().toJson(false) ............        "+new Gson().toJson(true));
    return (new Gson().toJson(true));
}
```

Comment: check whether,  `$("#pwdOverride").change(function(){alert('test')}) is working or not

Comment: Im suspect of `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` being in the string literal url. What do you expect that bit of code to do? If you watch the dev console network trace, what (if any) request is being made?

Comment: @Sravan. Yes its getting called and i was able to alert var pwdOverride = $("#pwdOverride").val();  and works fine.

Comment: If you can call the url (authenticationChk) in the getJson code, how possible it is not called? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Jamiec. It just gets the context. Network trace doesnt show url . No error in console from developer tools .

Comment: Ok i got it work changed the requestParam name to match with what is sent. My bad. Thanks all.